# Sum integer and char

Tags: char, integer

```
int i = 12;
char myChar = '4';
WriteLine(i + myChar);
```

// 64 because  ASCII '4' = 52

```
WriteLine(i  + myChar - '0');
```

//will be 16, what i want.
Why i should use  -'0'.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a digit *character* `'0'` to `'9'` a digit *value* `0` to `9`, subtract `'0'`.

This always works as C defines the *characters* `'0'` to `'9'` to be sequentially encoded.

```
//             v----------v  Arithmetic value of digit character.
WriteLine(i  + myChar - '0');
```

This works even if characters are not encoded with ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Ascii value `'0'` starts from `48` and as you know `'4'` is `52`.
if you subtract '0' from '4' you will get the value of integer 4 because
in ascii table values increses +1 frequency.

values:

```
'0' = 48
'1' = 49        {'1' - '0' == 49-48 == 1}
'2' = 50        {'2' - '0' == 50-48 == 2}
...
...
```

every time you subtract '0' which equals 48 you will get the real value of string number

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 12;
char myChar = '4';
WriteLine(i + (int)myChar);
```